# How to resolve template literals issue in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am using a template literals to construct a string and final append it to div

mainUrl parameter look like = `"<iframe src="youtube.com/78/76" ></iframe>"`

When finally i append this to div and view the `mainUrl` text is displayed on whole button text i am not able to understand why i am getting this instead i want to pass the `mainUrl` into button onclick function.

```
const activitiesBinding = (mainUrl) => {
    let reference = `<div class="row">
                              <div class="col">
                                  <div class="float-right">
                                        ${mainUrl ? `<button onclick="setSrc(${mainUrl})" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning"><i class="far fa-play-circle"></i> Watch</button>` : `<input type=hidden>`}
                                  </div> 
                              </div>
                     </div>`
```

Comment: It looks like you have 4 ` characters. You should figure out a way to get rid of one set or maybe turn it into two strings.

Comment: I tried this also but still issue is not resolved

Answer (score 2):

This is the HTML you are generating:

```
<button onclick="setSrc(<iframe src="youtube.com/78/76" ></iframe>)" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning">
                X                   X                   X
```

- The first X marks the start of the onclick attribute.
- The second X marks the end of the onclick attribute
- The third X marks the end of button start tag

You forgot to escape your nested quotes (`&quot;`) and to put the string literal you are passing to the setSrc function in quotes at all.

You have to be **very careful** about where your quotes go and when they get escaped when you are trying to mash strings together to create HTML. That goes double when you are creating HTML with JavaScript embedded in it.

It’s more verbose, but much less error prone to use `createElement`, `appendChild` and friends.

Comment: Thanks i know this issue but if i use ```createElement``` and ```appenChild``` then how will i pass it to onclick function

Comment: Change setSrc to expect a DOM element instead of a string.